# How to delete an input field after clicked on radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After clicked on the "Number of tweets from a date", the "Select end period" input field must be deleted. Can someone help me? This is the code:

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
  } else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">Select period <br>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">Number of Tweets from a date<br><br>
  <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
    Number of desired tweets <input type="number" min="1" max="20" id='yes' name='yes'><br>
  </div>


  <br>
  <img src="icon2.png"><label for="date">Select begin period:</label><br>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="Test_DatetimeLocal"><br><br>
  <img src="icon2.png"><label for="date">Select end period:</label><br>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="Test_DatetimeLocal"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the as same as your `#ifYes` tag. Wrap the input and label with an `div`, assign it an `id`, then just use `document.getElementById('select-end-period').style.display = 'none';`

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('select-end-period').style.display = 'none';

  } else {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('select-end-period').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">Select period <br>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">Number of Tweets from a date<br><br>
  <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
    Number of desired tweets <input type="number" min="1" max="20" id='yes' name='yes'><br>
  </div>


  <br>
  <img src="icon2.png"><label for="date">Select begin period:</label><br>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="Test_DatetimeLocal"><br><br>
  <div id="select-end-period">
    <img src="icon2.png"><label for="date">Select end period:</label><br>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="Test_DatetimeLocal"><br><br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
</form>
```